# https://github.com/twilio/hurl and Heroku

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, github, rack

https://github.com/twilio/hurl

I can't achieve the running server on Heroku by the steps from the readme file.

steps I did:

```
git clone git://github.com/twilio/hurl
cd hurl
gem install bundler
bundle install
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

using `heroku logs` I see the error of getting connection to `PG`

```
"/app/app/models/db.rb:16:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::Error)"
```

please help what I'm doing wrong..

**update:**

```
file:`db.rb`
    15      class PostgresDB < AbstractDB
    16        CONN = PG::Connection::new(
    17         ENV.fetch("POSTGRES_HOST", "localhost"),
    18          ENV.fetch("POSTGRES_PORT", 5432), 
    19          :dbname => ENV.fetch("POSTGRES_DATABASE", "hurls"),
    20          :user => ENV.fetch("POSTGRES_USER", "postgres"),
    21          :password => ENV.fetch("POSTGRES_PASSWORD", "postgres")
    22        )
```

Changed the details from the config heroku addon server of postgresql and got this error:

```
Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 16112`
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: INSERT INTO hurls VALUES ($1::varchar, $2::bytea)
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1137:in `new'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/models/db.rb:39:in `exec': ERROR:  relation "hurls" does not exist (PG::Error)
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/app.rb:35:in `initialize'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `new'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:                     ^
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1137:in `new'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/helpers.rb:69:in `each'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:13:in `block in <main>'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:162:in `app'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rackup:19:in `load'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:248:in `wrapped_app'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rackup:19:in `<main>'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:100:in `start'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/helpers.rb:70:in `block in setup_default_hurls'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/helpers.rb:69:in `setup_default_hurls'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/app.rb:245:in `save_hurl'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `eval'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/db.rb:39:in `save'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `parse_file'
2013-02-14T07:55:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:213:in `start'
2013-02-14T07:55:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-02-14T07:55:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-02-14T07:55:43+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=my-hurl-*****.herokuapp.com fwd=95.65.21.178 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

**Anyone achieved the working heroku server?**

Comment: do you have a database added? `heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev -a <app_name>`. This is created automatically for Rails apps, but probably not in this case.

Comment: not the case, heroku added an addon "Heroku Postgres Dev :: Ivory"

Comment: also with command "$ heroku config" I see the configuration of "DATABASE_URL:" and "HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_IVORY_URL:" which is the same

Comment: can you connect to the db with `heroku pg:psql`?

Comment: That connection block needs to be updated to use your `DATABASE_URL`

Comment: the question why heroku use this settings?

Comment: Please consider opening a pull request on the README on GitHub when you figure out the steps needed so that others will have an easier time.

Comment: updated the post, still don't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**solved**

added all configuration variables using:

```
$ heroku config:add POSTGRES_DATABASE=your_database
$ heroku config:add POSTGRES_HOST=your_host
$ heroku config:add POSTGRES_USER=your_user
$ heroku config:add POSTGRES_PASSWORD=your_password
$ heroku config:add POSTGRES_PORT=5432
```

**or in one line:** `$ heroku config:add POSTGRES_DATABASE=your_database POSTGRES_HOST=your_host POSTGRES_USER=your_user POSTGRES_PASSWORD=your_password POSTGRES_PORT=5432`

else create the tables manually:

```
$ heroku pg:psql
create table users (id character(40), content bytea);
create table hurls (id character(40), content bytea);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than the files in the config directory, generated by rails console, the gemfile too needs to be properly edited to work with postgresql, normally rails generate db.rb to use sqlite3 and same db is mentioned in gemfile too, they both needs to work with postgresql as heroku uses postgres, hope it might help.